# PHP - auto assign a different name to a variable of variable

Tags: php, variables

Using PHP variable variables with mysqli_fetch_assoc to auto-format variables like $column_name="some_value" (code below):

```
while ($account_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($account_results))
    {
    foreach ($account_row as $key=>$value)
        {
        $$key=trim(stripslashes($value));
        }
    }
```

So if I have a column "username" and row value "someuser", this code creates:

```
$username="someuser";
```

However, in some cases I need variable names to be DIFFERENT from column names. For example, I need code  to create:

```
$username_temp="someuser";
```

How could I do that? Using this code gives an error:

```
$$key."_temp"=trim(stripslashes($value));
```

No other ideas in my head.

Comment: $tempkey=$key."_temp"; $$tempkey=trim(stripslashes($value));  ?

Answer (score 1):

change `$$key."_temp"` to `${$key."_temp"}` have a look on below solution:

```
$value = 'test';
$key="someuser";
${$key."_temp"}=$value;
echo $someuser_temp; //output test
```

Comment: Thank you ALL, everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `${$key . "_temp"} = trim(stripslashes($value));`